# Isn't this C code creating a dangling pointer?

Tags: c, c99

Reading some code I came across this

```
static void initializeX11SBConfig(X11SBConfig* sbConfig) {
    X11SBConfig defX11SBConfig = {
        .sbStyle = SB_STYLE_W32,
        .sbFgColor = RGB(0, 0, 0),
        .sbBgColor = RGB(255, 255, 255),
        .sbOverScroll = FALSE
    };
    defX11SBConfig.sbWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
    *sbConfig = defX11SBConfig;
}
```

AFAICT `defX11SBConfig` is an automatic variable so on exit `sbConfig`will be pointing to some no longer valid location in the stack. Things should bomb quite fast as those color references are used oftenly elsewhere in the program. But they just don't.

My C is very rusty so I might be forgetting about initialized structs being allocated on the hgeap by default or something..

Also, what woud be better here? mallocing the struct? requiring a preallocated struct being pinted by sbConfig on entering? some other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The address of the local variable is not taken; its value is copied (to the object specified by the `sbConfig` pointer).

This line:

```
*sbConfig = defX11SBConfig;
```

Copies the entire structure value from `defX11SBConfig` to the location specified by `sbConfig`. (You seem to be under the impression instead that it stores the *address* of defX11SBConfig in a non-local pointer variable). The address of `defX11SBConfig` does not leak from the function; there is no dangling pointer. The `sbConfig` parameter is itself not modified (only what it points to). Furthermore, even if `sbConfig` were modified, its value would not leak since the change would not be reflected to the caller.

In C, if you never take the address of a local variable using the address-of operator `&`, then that address can not leak from its containing function.

Comment: oh, I see now. Rusty C language on my part indeed. The assumption here is that sbConfig is already pointing to some pre-allocated `X11SBConfig`struct o sutably sized block of memory on entering, right?